# What can i use instead of event which is deprecated?

Tags: javascript, events, keycode

i need to move the element by the arrows (arrowUp arrowDown and so on)but event key/keyCode is deprecated. So what can i use instead of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [KeyboardEvent.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to see [W3C specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#dom-keyboardevent-code) for a detailed explanation